# What would be the best way to power 10 AAA powered torches with mains power (240v)

Tags: power, source

We manufacture small AAA powered RGB torches. To test them I'd like to power up 10 at a time with crocodile clips. Ideally, the power source would be a mains powered supply. Would wiring off a multi-battery charger be a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Battery chargers are not intended for this application.  Depending on the battery it's designed to charge, you will get unpredictable performance.  I would look for dedicated power supplies to power your torches.  This can be a simple wall-wart from numerous online sources or it could be a dedicated power supply design.  If this is simply a go/no-go test then the wall-wart would probably suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the design of your torches (CanEnglish "flashlights).

Many small LED flashlights powered by three AAA cells depend on the internal resistance of the AAA cells to limit the current through the LEDs.  If your flashlights are like this, with no separate current regulation, then powering them from a normal DC power supply will likely burn out or damage the LEDs, as the power supply would probably be capable of delivering more current than the LEDs can tolerate.  In this case, you would need a current-limiting regulator for each flashlight you wish to test.

If your flashlights do have a current regulator, then you could safely use a normal DC power supply of the appropriate voltage.

Comment: LED have more resistance than AAA cells.